# Auto populate table after portlet is deployed in liferay

Tags: database, service, liferay, portlet, populate

I need a way to automatically populate a table created by the service builder of a portlet that is deployed in liferay. How can I accomplish that? I was thinking of a startup hook, but I won't be able to access the service of the particular portlet. So is there a way to populate it through the portlet itself ?

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to not make the changes destructive (e.g. be careful not to populate on every startup) you can do it in a StartupAction (or startup hook). You can add this hook to your portlet project - this works just fine. Alternatively you could declare a hook to be dependent on a portlet (or vice versa) in liferay-plugin-package.properties - this will make the services available. But for this purpose, I'd just package everything in one portlet plugin.

If you might have destructive changes in there, an Upgrade Action will be a safer bet: This is guaranteed to run only once.

For examples see the old sevencogs sample (let me know if you need pointers, then I'll get them out)

*Update*: To include such a hook in a portlet project, add WEB-INF/liferay-hook.xml with the following content (or use Liferay IDE's wizard to just add a hook to the project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_1_0.dtd">

<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
</hook>
```

Also, create WEB-INF/src/portal.properties with the following option

```
application.startup.events=com.example.MyStartupAction
```

and, of course, create the mentioned startup action, extending `com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.SimpleAction`

Comment: I added a portlet.properties file in my portlet and added `application.startup.events=com.‌​startup.StartupTest` to it, and created the class extending `SimpleAction` but it does not run. Can't we implement this in a portlet ?

Answer (score -1):

Try by deleting an entry from servicecomponent table. And redeploy your portlet.

```
delete FROM servicecomponent where buildNamespace="<your table namespace>"
```